# How to implement onItemClickListener on each item in the ListView to go to another activity?

Tags: android

How to implement `onItemClickListener` on each item in the `ListView` to go to another activity / to a new class?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ListView list;
    String[] itemname ={
            "Resturants",
            "Coffee Shops",
            "Hotels",
            "Gas Stations",
            "Hospitals",
            "Airports",
            "ATM",
            "Cinemmas",
            "Phamacies"
    };
    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.restaurantz,
            R.drawable.coffeeshop,
            R.drawable.hotel,
            R.drawable.gaspump,
            R.drawable.hospitalblue,
            R.drawable.airporticon,
            R.drawable.atm,
            R.drawable.cinemma,
            R.drawable.hospitalblue,
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }                
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats your Question here ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Intent mainIntent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivitu.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);

Comment: I wanted to know how to implement the onitem listener so that when every item in the list view is clicked it opens another activity

Answer (score 1):

inside `onItemClick`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
```

if you need to differenciate the clicked item, you can use the position parameter, for example:

```
if (position == 0)
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```